# Does the iPhone / iPod touch cache data also on disk, or only in memory?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am not sure, but I think I was reading a while ago that iPhone / iPod Touch don't cache anything to disk. They cache only in memory. So cache is not persistet when app quits. After relaunch of app it will re-fetch the data from the net. Is that true?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. If we have to reverse engineer your question by looking a the tags to figure out what you are talking about then your question was not complete enough.

Comment: It looks like this is a follow-on question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127075/what-could-i-do-in-nsurlconnection-connectionwillcacheresponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore this yourself using the iPhone Simulator, opening a terminal or using the Finder, and going to `~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/ then opening whatever directory your application is in.

You'll see a `Documents` directory, a `Library` and a `tmp` directory.

I've never looked to see if UIWebView is caching anything, but I know that Core Data will.

If you just suck down data yourself using CFNetwork, I believe it's up to you to cache the data yourself by saving it to `tmp` or `Documents` if you want.

`tmp` will not get backed up by the iTunes Sync process, but `Documents` will, so don't use `Documents` for temporary cache. Otherwise you'll just waste space and slow down sync backups.

The Documents directory will persist through anything, including app upgrades, except outright deleting the application using the Springboard or doing a total device storage wipe.

Actually the Library directory has directories. called Cache, WebKit/LocalStorage, and Preferences. So that would suggest something or the other.

Don't write to the application bundle directory or bad things could happen.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone OS disables on-disk caching from NSURLCache on this platform. If you need on-disk caching support anyway, you can use http://github.com/rs/SDURLCache which gives back on-disk cache support on iPhone OS

Answer (score -2):

iPhone apps can write data to disk.

Comment: Please provide more detailed information. We all know it can, please also pay more attention to the question. Thought if im going to downvote you i might as well explain why